# Is it possible to integrate the deep learning neural network built in python into MATLAB code?

Tags: python, matlab

I am wondering if there is a way to link the deep neural network built in python and use it in MATLAB code? for example, suppose I built a deep neural network as a function in python, so I need to call it in MATLAB code as a function in order to used it with MATLAB. Is that possible? if so, anyone can provide me a guidance or the steps to do that.

thank you

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import pretrained networks in MATLAB if you have access to the Deep Learning Toolbox.

You can use the [importKerasNetwork](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importkerasnetwork.html;jsessionid=397a72793b54b95c42a24a1f6a1f) function for Tensorflow-Keras networks, [importCaffeNetwork](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importcaffenetwork.html) for Caffe networks or [importONNXNetwork](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importonnxnetwork.html) for ONNX networks.

Comment: Thank you so much .. could you please share an example for that? I'm working with tensorflow

Comment: @Gze You are welcome. Have you already exported the model and weights?